# Load data during angular config state

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

**Introduction:**

A third-party navigation directive for an application sidebar, recommends loading data during the configuration phase. The menu items are dynamic, and are resolved on the server based on user credentials.

**Problem Statment:**

While the data loads fine, the then() clause defined in the code below is never executed, and as a result, the menus are not populated.

**Question:**

Can anyone suggest a way of resolving the promise in the configuration phase.

**What responses are helpful**

- An approach that resolves the above questions without radically altering the code, or
- An approach which radically changes the code, with an explanation, e.g. more elegant way, far shorter way, current code is an anti-pattern, or something I did not think of.

**What responses are not helpful**

- Use another component library, or library poorly designed (this is what I'm using, I'm looking for suggestions how to get it to work)
- or why are you doing x, y or z (I will gladly listen to suggestions)

**Update:** Added 'what has not worked' at the end.

Thank you,

PS. I doubt it is relevant, but just in-case, the libraries in use are:

Data: [js-data](http://www.js-data.io/)
Navigation: [eeh-navigation](https://github.com/ethanhann/eeh-navigation/)

### **The Code**

Service:

```
   .service('init', function initFactory(DS) {

        return DS.defineResource('init', {
            name: 'init',
            idAttribute: 'id',
            endpoint: '/init',
            basePath: 'http://localhost:63342/api'
        }).findAll({idAttribute: 'id'});

    })
```

Provider

```
    .provider("initProvider", ['DSProvider', function (DSProvider) {

            this.$get = ["init", function initFactory(init) {
                return new init(init);
            }]

    }])
```

Config

```
    .config(["initProvider", 'navProvider', function(initProvider, navProvider) {


            initProvider.$get().then(function (init) {

                    angular.forEach(init, function (value, key) {

                        navProvider.sidebarMenuItem(value.name, {
                            text: value.text,
                            iconClass: value.iconClass,
                            href: value.url
                        });
                    })


            })
    }])
```

**What has not worked (thus far)**

@Bricktop suggested using a promise to (i think) the provider, this is the change, but ;( unfortunately it does not work, the .then is never reached.

Provider:

```
                var promise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (new init(init)) {
                            resolve(init);
                        } else {
                            reject('failed');
                        }
                    }, 1000);
                });

                return promise;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not overly familiar with the use of providers, as they aren't used all that often, but I think I have an Idea that resolves your problem.

The `.then` you are using requires a promise to work, it is called whenever the previous promise is resolved and will execute a function on success or failure. I don't think however that your provider returns a promise but instead just returns a service.

To return a promise you should be able to use `$q` documented [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) With a correct promise setup your `then` should be executed. I hope this helps to fix your problem, I will try to improve my answer if it doesn't.

Here is a snippet showing what I mean:

```
this.$get = ["init", function initFactory(init) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  deferred.resolve(new init(init));
  return deferred.promise;
}]
```